# What is the difference between a protocol and a named bookmark in Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

An ActivityExecutionContext has three ways of creating bookmarks: CreateBookmark, CreateNamedBookmark and CreateProtocolBookmark.

1. Which one is supposed to be used for what kind of asynchronous operation?
2. What is the difference between a named and a protocol bookmark?
3. Which of the two does `CreateBookmark()` return and why the special case? It appears to behave like an named bookmark only without the name part judging from its behavior and [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector).

Answer (score 0):

As of now BETA 1 is just released, and so far I have seen only examples of createNamedBookmark for asynchronous operation.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/07/15/more-asynchronous-work-in-windows-workflow-foundation-4.aspx

There is no documentation from MSDN for the protocol framework, so I guess only WF Core team could answer your question as of now. Otherwise, you will have to wait till the next release.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.activityexecutioncontext.createprotocolbookmark%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for pointing to my own blog :-)

I don't really understand CreateProtocolBookmark() yet. However I understand it is a very low level API that is used internally and CreateNamedBookmark() is normally the correct route to go.

Comment: @Maurice, i am your regular reader of your blog and keep posting about WF 4.0.